# Convert string date name to datetime or string date

Tags: mysql, sql

In one of my DB column i have a string like this

```
19-Oct-19
```

i want to change this string to a proper date format like this

```
19-10-2019  or 19-10-2019
```

how can i achieve this with sql

Comment: 19-Oct-19 is a good example of an unclear date format. Does the leading 19 mean day or year? Does the ending 19 mean year or day? However, never store dates as strings, use proper date data type instead.

Comment: yes, I know got the data from some customer and dumped that data directly into the table now trying to convert the same.
leading 19 is the year 2019.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `STR_TO_DATE()` you can convert `String` to `Date` and with `DATE_FORMAT()` format your `Date` value.

```
select DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE('19-Oct-19', '%Y-%M-%d'), '%d-%m-%Y');
```